# create formula with sumif,if and ,or

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to make formula with sumif and with conditions i tried but its failing to provide sum.I want to find value if conditions:
1. G/L is 62810101 or 62810100 then value for 81810101 and 81810100 should be calculated or vice versa.
2.If code is A2+B2 then value for B2+A2 should be find in document currency.

i tried something like this... =IF(OR(E2=62810101,E2=62810100),SUMIFS(I:I,L:L,L2,E:E,E2=81810101))

```
CoCd    Tr.Prt  DocumentNo  Reference   G/L Doc. Date   Amount in local cur.    LCurr   Amount in doc. curr.    Curr.   Code 1  Sum if 1
BG05    RS31    1100000007  111 62810100    42081   2542.58 BGN 1300    EUR BG05RS31    2918
BG05    RS31    1100000017  1100000017  81810101    42234   621.95  BGN 318 EUR RS31BG05    318
```

Comment: It is slightly unclear.  Do you want to sum column I when Column E equals 62810101,62810100,818810101, or 81810100?  Because that is what your formula is hinting at but your narrative makes it seem like the 62810101,62810100 and the 818810101, 81810100 are in different columns.  Which is true?

Comment: no that are in same column but i did some mistake in formula which i cant find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these formula:

For Accts Receivable:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(I:I,L:L,L2,E:E,{62810101,62810100}))
```

For Accts Payable:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(I:I,L:L,L2,E:E,{81810101,81810100}))
```

[image]

It is just a matter of putting the wanted account numbers in the `{}` brackets.

Comment: formula is ok... but i want to add opposite values.... 62810101 and 62810100 is opposite of 81810101 and 81810100...
So if its 62810100 then it should sum only 81810100 and 81810101

Comment: I don't understand.  Could you elaborate?

Comment: 62810100 ,62810101,etc are accounts starting fro 6 are Account receivables and starting from 8 is account payable.....
so i am calculating accounts receivable balance in 1 column and account payable in another column ...
so any one group should be calaculated at a time....